# Total number of saguna parabrahmans in Hinduism

Tags: gods, brahman

[Parabrahman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Para_Brahman) is the highest supreme god in Hinduism. [Saguna brahman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saguna_brahman) refers to the parabrahman with gunas.

Saguna brahman is also called as Upasya Brahman.

Siva, Vishnu, Krishna, Rama, Balarama, Radha, Kali, Bhuvaneswari etc., are (some) saguna parabrahmans as per scriptures.

Are saguna parabrahmans finite? If yes, then how many Gods of **saguna Parabrahman** stature are there in Hinduism?

Comment: Nice question. You probably mean personification of the parabrahman.

Comment: @Wikash_ Yeah.... true......

Comment: Parabrahman refers to Nirguna Brahman. Saguna Brahman refers to Iswara. We only perceive Brahman through Saguna Brahman. The various names of the Lord refer to his embodiment as Saguna Brahman.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda yeah, edited.

Comment: There will not be many Saguna Brahamans, but only one.  Saguna Brahman is the visible form of Nirguna Brahman only.  Nature is the Saguna Brahman of the Nirguna Brahman.  Sri Krishna says this much only in Gita,@hanugm

Comment: Then what about manifestations of the Saguna Brahman in different forms? @srimannarayanakv

Comment: Those forms appeared according to the devotee's perception.  Sri Ramakrishna's sincere devotion, reflected in the form of Kali.  Tukaram's devotion reflected in the form of Vittal, Tulasidas's devotion appeared in the form of Sri Rama,  etc.  @hanugm

Comment: But Kali was mentioned in scriptures before Ramakrishna and Ram was also mentioned in scriptures before Tulsidas as saguna Brahmans. 

Suppose If some devotee prays with a new name and new shape which are not mentioned in scriptures, then can it be also a saguna brahman? @srimannarayanakv

Comment: Valmiki never stated that Sri Rama was God.  The interpolated stories may say so.  The devotion of a person can manifest in any form, be it in female form or male form.@hanugm

Comment: @srimannarayanakv So, according to you, Jesus is also a Saguna Brahman? And any human being can be a saguna Brahman?

Comment: I think you have not understood what I said.  Even a great sage like Shri Shirdi Sai , who performed miracles, never said that he was God.  A true sage/godly person will never say that.  It is devotees perception that matters.  Sri Ramakrishna's devotion reflected in the form of Jesus also.  Please check his story.@hanugm

Comment: @srimannarayanakv So, according to you there can be infinite saguna brahamans because the perception of devotees is the only criteria. Is it correct? Please say a number: 1 or infinity?

Comment: As I already said NATURE is the visible form of the God.  Remaining are perceptions only.  So they can be infinite.@hanugm

Comment: @hanugm what you are basically asking is how much different forms of deities are there. There more deities. Shaktis different forms. And isvaras different forms. You're seeing in lens of prskriti thats why u think there are many saguna brahmans. Parabrahman is only one. Not many.

Comment: @ParabrahmanJyoti Does each diety is a Saguna brahman?

Comment: @hanugm different deities come from panchabootha principle.  They're not brahman. But main debate of brahman lies in Shiva vishnu shakti. But for that you need to know principles of manifestation to know the Adi Purusha. The Parabrahman.

Comment: Your questions answer lies in your own Yoga sadhana. Not in scriptures.

Comment: I ll tell you simple thing. How many languages call water as different name? Water in English, Jal, Paani, thannir, neer, theertham etc.. all these point water. Does this mean, there are infinite water with different names>? Thats the answer!

Comment: @ParabrahmanJyoti You are saying about qualities of parabrahman. But afaik every manifestation cannot be a saguna brahman.

Comment: @hanugm I am also saying same.

Answer (score 2):

Rig vedic seers foresaw this type of doubts long back.  That was why they stated that there is only ONE BRAHMAN, but might be called in different names by the knowledgeable persons.

Rig Veda [I.164.46](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rvsan/rv01164.htm)

> इन्द्रं मित्रं वरुणमग्निमाहुरथो दिव्यः स सुपर्णो गरुत्मान | ***एकं सद***
> विप्रा बहुधा वदन्त्यग्निं यमं मातरिश्वानमाहुः ||
>
> They call him Indra, Mitra, Varuṇa, Agni, and he is heavenly
> nobly-winged Garutmān. To what is ***One***, sages give many a title
> they call it Agni, Yama, Mātariśvan.

---

Same mantra can be applied to the present day different deities, Shiva, Vishnu, Ganapati, Shakti, etc.